# Adobe Commerce Cloud Azure Integration

Tags: magento2.4, magento2-cloud, cloud, architecture

Does Adobe Commerce Cloud console login provide an ability to login via Azure AD instead of Adobe ID?

Similarly, does Adobe Commerce Admin provide an ability to login via Azure AD instead of user credentials created from the Commerce backend?